# Twitter Bootstrap reducing well and field widths

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found some code online for a registration form that I am trying to tweak for my needs.

I am trying to make the well width smaller but I notice that `<div class="well well-sm">` and `<div class="well">` does not change the size of the well.

Setting a fixed with, e.g.  `<div class="well" style="width: 600px">` makes the well left aligned on the page instead of centering it which is what I want. How do I make the well width smaller?

Also, what is the proper way of fixing the width of the textfields to prevent them from becoming too wide on browser collapse/grow?

[`Demo.`](http://jsfiddle.net/MSv5h/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`well-sm` does not make that much of a difference since it's not meant to alter the proportions so drastically, but only to make minute difference in forms.
You can add a `width` value, but to centre it you have to also add `margin: 0 auto;`. Here's a [fiddle showing what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/MSv5h/3/).

**Regarding textbox resizing:** The problem is that the element you're using (`col-sm-6`) sets width to 50%, but this only works when the browser has at least a width of `768px`, check out this following CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) //for this to work, at least 768px are needed
.col-sm-6 {
width: 50%;
}
```

When you have less than 768px, the second class (`col-xs-12`) becomes active. This takes 100% width. If you use `col-xs-6` instead, it will resize to 50%.
So what you need to do, is to change the class containing the text fields from `col-sm-6 col-xs-12` to `col-sm-6 col-xs-6`.

Comment: Just make sure to understand how `.col-sm-1` to `.col-sm-12` etc work in bootstrap. It's very empowering. Best of luck!